# Jodconverter libreoffice OpenOfficeException:could not load input document

Tags: java, libreoffice, jodconverter

I am using JODCONVERTER 2.2  Webapp along with libreoffice headless . And its throwing this error could not load input document

They are in the same machine and i am getting this trace , any help appreciated

```
exception

com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed: could not load input document
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.loadAndExport(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:131)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:120)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:104)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:88)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:82)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.web.DocumentConverterServlet.doPost(DocumentConverterServlet.java:71)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL seems to be an unsupported one.
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:182)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:148)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:344)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:313)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:101)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:652)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:154)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:136)
$Proxy20.loadComponentFromURL(Unknown Source)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.loadDocument(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:150)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.loadAndExport(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:127)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:120)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:104)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:88)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:82)
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.web.DocumentConverterServlet.doPost(DocumentConverterServlet.java:71)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs.
```

Comment: It could help if you posted your code and mentioned the version of  libreOffice you are using.

Answer (score 0):

sorry about that . It was libreoffice 4 . And the issue was i needed to install the libreoffice writer and it solved the issue .